# How do I run multiple sets of regressions in SPSS without having to retype the command each time?

Tags: spss

How do I run multiple sets of regressions in SPSS without having to retype the command each time or without having to change the dependent variable every single time manually?

I need to run a lot of regressions with the same independent variables but I need to change the dependent variable. Is there a possibility to make this process easier?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Write a simplest macro (see DEFINE command help). Because your question is not statistical but programmic I erased tags beyond "spss"

Answer (score 4):

Note also that if you have to repeat this process for each country, you can use SPLIT FILES with the country id, and statistical procedures, including REGRESSION, will automatically iterate over each country.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have 50 dependent variables, each of which needs to be regressed on the same predictors using the same regression options. Paste your list of dependent variables into Excel as a vertical list (cells b1:b50).  Into cells a1:a:50 paste that part of your regression syntax that comes before the name of the dependent variable, right up to and including "/dependent ".  Into cells c1:c50 paste the part of your syntax that follows the name of the dependent variable.  Then in cell d1 type "=concatenate(a1,b1,c1)".  Paste that formula down through cells d2:d50 and you'll have your 50 commands to paste into a syntax window.  It may show gridlines; SPSS will not have any problem with these.

btw, What sort of research context is it that requires these identically-configured regressions for a large number of outcomes?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have, however found a solution that works as well.

Comment: I wrote a syntax that looks like this (I want "a" to be my independent variable)
REGRESSION VARIABLES = a b c ... z
/DEP = b c ... z /METHOD = ENTER.

I am trying to investigate whether a specific commodity index growth rate influences stock market indices growth rate for specific countries.

Comment: Yeah, this the easiest solution. Right.